# Does passing "pointer to structure" to a function create local copies of it in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure like this

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

Which I use to create singly linked list.

I created other functions like

```
int push(struct node* head,int element);
```

which pushes data onto stack created using node structs.

The function then tries to update the `struct node* head` passed to it using code(it does other things as well)

```
head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The call is made as such

```
struct node* stack;
push(stack,number);
```

It looks like this code created copy of the pointer passed to it. So I had to change the function to

```
int push(struct node** head,int element)
```

and

```
*head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The call is made as such

```
struct node* stack;
push(&stack,number);
```

So my question is, what was the earlier function doing? Is it necessary to pass `struct node**` to the function if I want to update original value of pointer or is my approach wrong?

Sorry I cannot provide complete code as it is an assignment.

Comment: C passes by value, even when the value passed is a reference to something else.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Clarification: C does not support references (this term has a well defined meaning in programming). You likely mean "address".

Comment: @Olaf Pointers are C's way to implement references. Why do you think `*` is called the *dereference* operator? I don't want to get bogged down in terminology -- but the Wikipedia article on references in computer science mentions pointers as an example of a reference type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science). But - you are probably correct that someone coming from a different language might misunderstand my meaning there.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Technically you are right: a reference is a pointer. But one which is no object of its own right. All accesses to the reference actually affect the object it _points_ to. A (normal) pointer otoh is a normal object with type and value. To access the object it _points_ to, you have to apply a special function/operator (in C: the dereference operator), otherwise you access its value. This differentiation is quite common, but you are right, there should be a more clear term to differentiate between the two concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C always passes by value. To change a variable passed to a function, instead of passing the variable itself, you pass a reference(its address).

Let's say you're calling your function with the old signature

```
int push(struct node* head,int element);

struct node *actual_head = NULL;
push(actual_head, 3);
```

Now before calling push, your variable `actual_head` will have value as `NULL`.

Inside the push function, a new variable `head` will be pushed to stack. It will have the same value as passed to it, i.e. `NULL`.

Then when you call `head = malloc(...)`, your variable `head` will get a new value instead of `actual_head` which you wanted to.

To mitigate the above, you'll have to change the signature of your function to

```
int push(struct node** head,int element);

struct node *actual_head = NULL
push(&actual_head, 3);
```

Now if you notice carefully, the value of `actual_head` is `NULL`, but this pointer is also stored somewhere, that somewhere is its address `&actual_head`. Let's take this address as `1234`.

Now inside the push function, your variable `head` which can hold the address of a pointer(Notice the two *), will have the value of `1234`

Now when you do `*head = malloc(...)`, you're actually changing the value of the object present at location 1234, which is your `actual_head` object.

Answer (score 5):

C *always* passes parameters by value (i.e., by copying it). This applies even to pointers, but in that case, it is the pointer itself that is copied. Most of the times you use pointers, that is fine, because you are interested in manipulating the data that is pointed to by the pointer. However, in your situation, you want to modify the pointer itself, so you do indeed have to use a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not doing what you think but not because it creates a copy of the node, it creates a copy of the pointer.

Try printing

```
fprintf(stdout, "Address of head: %p\n", (void *) head);
```

both, inside `push()` and in the caller function.

The pointer you pass in and the parameter have different addresses in memory although they both point to the same address, storing the result of `malloc()` in it doesn't persist after the funcion has returned.

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer like this

```
int push(struct node **head, int element)
{
     /* Ideally, check if `head' is `NULL' and find the tail otherwise */
     *head = malloc(sizeof(**head));
     if (*node == NULL)
         return SOME_ERROR_VALUE;
     /* Do the rest here */
     return SOME_SUCCESS_VALUE_LIKE_0;
}
```

And to call it, just

```
struct node *head;
head = NULL;
push(&head, value);
/*   ^ take the address of head and pass a pointer with it */
```

of course, the `push()` implementation should be very differente but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: Actually I found out the problem using a similar printf statement.

Comment: Inspecting the data like this sometimes helps more than using a debugger, just sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The first version of your program was passing the pointer by value. Although it passed an address (held by the `pointer to struct`) it didn't pass the `pointer's address` - necessary to update the value.

Whenever you want to **update a variable's value** you must pass the **variable's address**. To pass a pointer address, you need a parameter `pointer to pointer to type`.

In your case, `pointer to pointer to struct node`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything everybody has said is absolutely correct in terms of your question. However, I think you should also consider the design. Part of your problem is that you are conflating the stack itself with the internal structures needed to store data on it. You should have a stack object and a node object. i.e.

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}

struct Stack
{
    struct Node* head;
}
```

Your push function can then take a pointer to the Stack without any double indirection.  Plus there is no danger of pushing something on to a node that is in the middle of the stack.

```
void push(struct Stack* stack, int value)
{
    struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof node);
    node->data = value;
    node->next = stack->head;
    stack->head = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
int push(struct node* head,int element) {
    head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

allocate some memory and throw it away (cause memory leak).

Passing “pointer to structure” to a function do create local copies of it.

It is necessary to pass `struct node**` to the function if you want to update original value of pointer. (using global variables is generally considered as a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `stack` to your function `push(struct node* head,int element)`

and do

```
head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The pointer `head` will update to the memory allocated by `malloc()` and `stack` is unaware of this memory as you just passed the value.(which is uninitialized here)

When you pass the address then you have a pointer to pointer which makes the changes inside `push()` to be reflected on `stack`

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, what was the earlier function doing?

Your earlier function was defined to receive a pointer to an object.  You passed your function an uninitialized struct node pointer.  A function can't do anything with a value representing an uninitialized pointer. So your function was passed garbage, but no harm was done because your function immediately ignored it by overwriting with a pointer to allocated memory.  Your function is not using the value you passed for anything except temporary local storage now.  Upon return from your function, your parameters to the function are thrown away (they are just copies), and the value of your stack variable is as it was before, still uninitialized.  The compiler usually warns you about using a variable before it is initialized.

By the way, the pointer value to the allocated memory was also thrown away/lost upon function return.  So there would now be a location in memory with no reference and therefore no way to free it up, i.e., you have a memory leak.

> Is it necessary to pass struct node** to the function if I want to update original value of pointer or is my approach wrong?

Yes, it is necessary to pass the address of a variable that you want filled in by the function being called.  It must be written to accept a pointer to the type of data it will supply.  Since you are referencing your object with a pointer, and since your function is generating a pointer to your object, you must pass a pointer to a pointer to your object.

Alternatively, you can return a pointer as a value from a function, for example

```
struct node * Function() { return (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); }
```

The call would be...

```
struct node *stack;
stack = Function();
if(stack == NULL) { /* handle failure */ }
```

So, your approach is not wrong, just your implementation (and understanding) need work.